# SharePoint 2013 Global Navigation Branding

Tags: 2013, navigation, css, branding

How can I get the Global navigation to ignore the core4.css and take up my custom styles.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this by including the following part in your html master.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_catalogs/masterpage/custom/css/custom-core.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/>-->
```

In the file »custom-core.css« you can simply override existing styles.

Comment: So will this allow me to override any of styles that are in coreV15?

Comment: Yes. If you use this part after the default css declaration you can override it.